# Can I force app-server communication not to use DHE/ECDHE?

Tags: tls, wireshark, decryption

I have **downloaded** an .exe app that communicates with server by use of TLS.
I want to look to the data being transferred.
In wireshark I see that when establishing connection they (app and server) choose

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

which as far as I know is hard to decrypt.
Can I disable this algorithms and leave only the RSA?
I am on windows 10, but have VM with ubuntu and xp. On windows is it Schannel.dll responsive for this rich list of available cipher suites?

```
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 508
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random
            Session ID Length: 0
            Cipher Suites Length: 154
            Cipher Suites (77 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a5)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a3)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x00a1)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0069)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x0068)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0037)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0036)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0087)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0086)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0085)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc02a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc026)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a4)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a0)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x009a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0099)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0098)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0097)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0044)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0043)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0042)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA (0x0096)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA (0x0007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc00c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc002)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
```

Comment: You need to export the master key, most frameworks offer this. This works with DH ciphers as well. But otherwise your client or server should allow to configure ciphers, you would remove them which you do not want to use.

Comment: And this should give you a nice overview how to do this https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/authentication/ssl-tls-hood-34297

Comment: @eckes, I don't have access to the server configuration and don't have the sources of an app. I've just downloaded an app and want to look to traffic being transferred.

Comment: If you have access to the truststore of the client you can also use a MITM proxy.

Comment: Can't you just hook the API of the SSL library and log all the data passing through?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, sorry, do yo mean I have access to the app's source? I had to mention I just downloaded an app and want to see decrypted traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for local MITM proxy. If it will not work because of untrusted certificate you have to try to install the proxy certificate to your Windows trusted certs store. If it still will not work you are lost as the exe is probably checking cert internally and you would need to hack it to get it work with "untrusted" cert. As a MITM proxy I would recommend OWASP ZAP or Burp.

Comment: thanks, It works with zap. Can I modify the server's response body?

Comment: Sure, you can do whatever you want there. Just intercept the request/response, modify as you wish and forward it.